# In which Moodle table are the tokens for the web services?

Tags: api, token, moodle

In which Moodle table are the tokens for the web services?

'''
prefix_tablename
'''

Thanks everyone for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The table is `mdl_external_tokens`